# Visual Studio でソリューションを読み込む事ができません。

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

UnityのプロジェクトでVisual Studioでコードを書いていたのですが、

Visual Studioで
「ソリューションを読み込む事ができませんでした」
「Load operation failed」
というエラーが出てしまっています。

他のプロジェクトだと大丈夫なのですが、このプロジェクトだけで起こっています。
一度再インストールしてみたのですがそれでも直りませんでした。
関係あるのかどうかわからないのですが、そのエラーが起こる前日にVisual Studioのアップデートがありました。

パソコンはmacを使っています。

どなたかわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 発生したエラーの情報がテキストかhtmlのファイルで何処かに出力されていませんか？ それを探してあれば追記してみてください。

Comment: [Visual Studio 2019 for Mac Release Notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-relnotes)の[Web and Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-relnotes#web-and-azure-1)に`We fixed an issue causing Cannot load solution on VisualStudio for Mac.`とあったので、もっと新しい版に更新していくと修正されるかもしれませんね。

Comment: Visual Studio、Unity共に新しい版に変えてみたところ修正されました。

Answer (score 1):

コメント頂けたので、Visual Studio、Unity共に新しい版に変えてみたところ修正されました。Unityのバージョンも関係があるのかもしれません。

追記　Unityは2017.4.40f1を使っていたのを2019.4.8f1にアップグレードしました。

Comment: 可能な範囲で構いませんので、新しいバージョン、及び問題が起きていた際のバージョンについての情報も記載があると、同じような問題が起きたユーザーがこの投稿を見た時に、より役立つ情報になると思います。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。初心者なのでありがたいです。さっそく回答欄の方に追加しておきます。書くところ等間違ってたらすみません。